# How add edit and delete to each of jquery dataTable?

Tags: jquery, ajax, datatables

While i am trying to view table using jquery dataTable at last column of each row i want to add edit and delete buttons.i want to update the database on every update and delete.How to do that?

Ajax :-

```
//Ajax to get idns sites by ruleId.
    var deleteButton='<i class="glyphicon glyphicon-remove" style="font-size:20px;"></i>';
    var editButton='<i class="glyphicon glyphicon-pencil" style="font-size:20px;"></i>';
    $.ajax({
        url : '/idns/site/getSitesByRuleId/'+rule_id,
        method : 'get',
        dataType : 'json',
        success:function(data){
            $('#siteDataTable').DataTable( {
                data:data,
                 "destroy": true,
                 "processing": true,
                columns: [{ data: 'siteId' },{ data: 'siteName' },{ data: 'userName' },{ data: 'channelName' },]
            } );
        }
    });
    // To edit site table record.
    var table = $('#siteDataTable').DataTable();

    $('#siteDataTable tbody').on( 'click', 'tr', function () {
        console.log(table.row( this ).data());
    } );
```

Here is [fiddle](http://www.jsfiddle.net/annoyingmouse/Lap4brgn):-

Comment: This can also be done to achieve this: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/53986908/how-to-add-edit-and-delete-link-in-jquery-datatable-plugin

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Did you tried [mRender](http://legacy.datatables.net/usage/columns) something like,

```
mRender: function (data, type, row) {
     return '<a class="table-edit" data-id="' + row[0] + '">EDIT</a>'
}
```

Use `console.log()` to understand the `row` object in `mRender` callback.

Comment: @Mr.Rohan Kumar thank you . I wish to learn javascript and in depth.kindly give resource like it will help me alot.

Comment: Actually in this field all is depend on `Logic and Concepts` and to learn anything, google itself is more than enough. So, googling always for errors.